# D3 JS - all data plotting on the same point unless graph is very wide

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, plot

I am using the following code to extract data from a database and then plot it on the D3 SVG canvas. I need to be able to show the data in the following formats: half hourly, hourly, daily, weekly, monthly and yearly. At the minute all of them except the 2 smallest ones are working fine.

When too much data gets added to the graph, everything starts plotting on the same X coordinate.

```
    <script>

function buildChart(groupby) {

    $('.svg-container').find('svg').empty();

    // Set the dateformat for the X axis and the dateFormat for the ticks
    if (groupby == '2') {
        var dateFormatPattern = '%Y';
        var tickFormatPattern = '%Y';
    } else if (groupby == '3') {
        var dateFormatPattern = '%B';
        var tickFormatPattern = '%B';
    } else if (groupby == '4') {
        var dateFormatPattern = 'Week %U';
        var tickFormatPattern = 'Week %U';
    } else if (groupby == '5') {
        var dateFormatPattern = '%b %d';
        var tickFormatPattern = '%b %d';
    } else if (groupby == '6') {
        var dateFormatPattern = '%b %d';
        var tickFormatPattern = '%c';
    }

    var margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = $('.svg-container').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format(dateFormatPattern)(new Date(d)); });

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + " kWh" });

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        // Format the date of the highlighted bar to output it consistently
        var formattedDate = d3.time.format(tickFormatPattern)(new Date(d.date));
        var tooltip_content = "<strong>Date:</strong> <span style='color: steelblue;'>" + formattedDate + "</span><br/>";
        tooltip_content += "<strong>Consumption:</strong> <span style='color:steelblue'>" + d3.format(".2f")(d.value) + " kWh</span>";
        return tooltip_content;
      })

    var svg = d3.select(".svg-container svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    /****
    *
    * Get the data
    *
    ****/

    $.post('http://127.0.0.1/data/getData.php?DanChart', {request:'{"electric":[{"id":"12"}]}', filters:'{"date":["range", "2013-11-05", "", "2013-11-12"], meter:[1], houseId2:[5]}', groupby: groupby}, function (data) {

      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.value); })]);

      console.log(data);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d) { 
            var day = new Date(d.date);
            console.log(day);
            if (day.getDay()%6==0 && groupby == '5') {
                return "bar weekend";
            } else {
                return "bar";
            }
          })
          //.attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

        // How many ticks are there?
        var numberOfTicks = data.length;
        // Work out the longest length of any tick
        var tickLength = 0;
        $(".svg-container").find('.x .tick').each(function(){
            if($(this)[0].getBBox().width > tickLength){
                tickLength = $(this)[0].getBBox().width;
            }
        });

        // Add some padding
        tickLength = tickLength + 10;

        // How many ticks could possibly fit across the X axis
        var maximumTicks = (width/tickLength);
        // Work out which occurance of tick should be shown. 
        // E.g. if tickRatio = 2, every other tick will be shown, starting from the first tick
        // So ticks 1,3,5,7 and so on will be visible and the others are hidden to prevent overlapping
        var tickRatio = Math.ceil(numberOfTicks/maximumTicks);

        // console.log('tickratio',tickRatio);
        // console.log('noofticks',numberOfTicks);
        // console.log('maximumTicks',maximumTicks);

        // Use CSS selectors to calcuate which ticks need hiding, and give them the class hidden-tick       
        if (tickRatio > 1) {
            $('.svg-container').find('.x .tick:not(:nth-child('+tickRatio+'n+1))').attr('class','tick hidden-tick');
        }

    });

}

/****
*
* Build initial chart, 5 is for daily records
*
****/

buildChart('6');

</script>
```

If I change the following line:

```
width = $('.svg-container').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
```

to:

```
width = 5000 - margin.left - margin.right,
```

so that the canvas is very wide, the data will fit fine and plot in the correct places.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fit all of the data on the graph with the original width?

An example of the dates I'm extracting for hourly transactions are:

```
Thu Aug 22 2013 19:19:27 GMT+0100 (BST)
Thu Aug 22 2013 20:00:57 GMT+0100 (BST)
Thu Aug 22 2013 21:00:38 GMT+0100 (BST)
Thu Aug 22 2013 22:00:21 GMT+0100 (BST)
Thu Aug 22 2013 23:00:51 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri Aug 23 2013 00:00:58 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri Aug 23 2013 01:00:01 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri Aug 23 2013 02:00:35 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri Aug 23 2013 03:00:18 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri Aug 23 2013 04:00:59 GMT+0100 (BST)
Fri Aug 23 2013 05:00:03 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is it possible that there are simply too many data points to spread out?

Comment: Yep that's probably the problem, is there any way I can get around it?

Comment: Show fewer data points, i.e. aggregate in some way?

Comment: I think I'll make it so that users can only view an X amount of days at a time. Problem is if they want to compare 3 months data to another 3 months for example. Can D3 plot all of the data but then let the user pan across so it's not all on view at once?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)?